# One's or ones possesive noun or not?

Tags: nouns, possessives, saxon-genitive, locatives

It is my first question on any stackoverflow site, so sorry if I have not researched the current available questions and answers enough (I tried), but I have thoroughly searched both the internet and the english stackoverflow site as well as I could (I was not sure as to what tag I should have searched to get the correct answer to my question).

That aside I am stuck as to whether I am using a possessive noun or a non possessive noun.

The question is pretty simple which sentence is correct.

1. Many other online IQ tests rely on knowledge orientated questions to test ones IQ.

*Or*

2. Many other online IQ tests rely on knowledge orientated questions to test one's IQ.

I understand one is correct and one is not, but it would be most helpful if someone could explain what the true difference between the two is, and when I should use one and not the other.

I am no English language expert, and I am sure this has been answered many times on this site but I could not find it, I am sure as I continue to use the stackoverflow websites I will become more efficient at finding answers to my questions. If anyone has any tips on how to do this I would be most grateful, maybe a little FAQ on how to search?

Comment: I understand where you are coming from with this question as whose is the possessive of who
However, like Jon Hanna said, one is different. I don't know the answer to why it is so but conventional English usage states that one's is the possessive of one.

Comment: The search I used to find the earlier question was: one's possessive

Comment: Thank you @MετάEd I am not too clued up with internet searching, took me half an hour to post the question in the correct format!!

Comment: Thank you for your contribution, but please note that the protocol on this site is *not* to create answers that add *nothing new* to existing answers. You've acknowledged Jon's answer, but added nothing new.

Comment: If you want reinforce and reccomend an existing answer, upvote it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*One's*

It's the one exception to the pronouns in not having a separate apostrophe-free genitive though historically there were others (*it's* and *who's* are now incorrect where one would use *its* or *whose*, but once upon a time this wasn't the case).

It can help one remember this, to consider that *ones* exists as the plural of other senses of *one*, and *one's* is a different word.

Comment: The one exception? Another's _another_: "In Another's Eyes", for example.

Comment: This is a great answer and shed some light onto it for me... Could you please give me an example of a correct usage and a on correct usage, so I could grasp it more?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I racked my brain after that dangerous "one exception" and for some reason *another* didn't come to me.